# Apify handlePageFunction should skip if content-type is not html

Tags: apify

I have the problem that the `Apify.utils.enqueueLinks` function adds also downloads or image links to the requestQueue.

Actually i tried to solve it this way:

```
handlePageFunction: async({
        request, response, page
    }) => {
        await page.waitFor(settings.waitForPageload)
        console.log(`Get Data from:: ${request.url}`)
        if(response.headers()['content-type'].includes('html')) {
          ...do all stuff here
        }
```

What would be a better solution for that?

Comment: Isn't it better to create more sophisticated pseudoUrl that will filter extensions etc.? An example would be good.

Comment: Is there an example for that - i think this is what im looking for. Btw thanks for your great support on every of my stackoverflow question!!!

Comment: I don't think there is a specific example of this. I would just play with different URLs and regexes. You can test your regex in Chrome dev console.